# Groovy syntax for regular expression matching

Tags: regex, groovy

What is the Groovy equivalent of the following Perl code?

```
my $txt = "abc : groovy : def";
if ($txt =~ / : (.+?) : /) {
  my $match = $1;
  print "MATCH=$match\n"; 
  # should print "MATCH=groovy\n"
}
```

I know that there's more than one way to do it (including the regular Java way) - but what is the "Groovy way" of doing it?

This is one way of doing it, but it feels a bit clumsy - especially the array notation (`m[0][1]`) which feels a bit strange. Is there a better way do it? If not - please describe the logic behind `m[0][1]`.

```
def txt = "java : groovy : grails"
if ((m = txt =~ / : (.+?) :/)) {
  def match = m[0][1]
  println "MATCH=$match"
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was the closest match to the Perl code that I could achieve:

```
def txt = "abc : groovy : def"
if ((m = txt =~ / : (.+?) : /)) {
  def match = m.group(1)
  println "MATCH=$match"
}

// Prints:
// MATCH=groovy
```

Comment: What will this print?  Looks confusing to the naked eye.

Comment: How does this work? What does this do? Looks confusing to the naked eye.

Comment: why do you wrap the ```m = txt =~ / : (.+?) : / ``` part in an if statements?

Comment: @Sajuuk because `=~` is an regex operator and if nothing will be found m would be null.

Comment: If you use `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic`, just add `Matcher m` before the `if`.

Comment: Why the double parenthesis in `((m=...))`. I can see that I get a an error without, but I don't understand why: `MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
.../test.groovy: 2: expecting ')', found '=' @`

Answer (score 106):

`m[0]` is the first match object.
`m[0][0]` is everything that matched in this match.
`m[0][1]` is the first capture in this match.
`m[0][2]` is the second capture in this match.

Based on what I have read (I don't program in Groovy or have a copy handy), given

```
def m = "barbaz" =~ /(ba)([rz])/;
```

`m[0][0]` will be `"bar"`
`m[0][1]` will be `"ba"`
`m[0][2]` will be `"r"`
`m[1][0]` will be `"baz"`
`m[1][1]` will be `"ba"`
`m[1][2]` will be `"z"`

I could not stand not knowing if I was correct or not, so I downloaded groovy and wrote an example:

```
def m = "barbaz" =~ /(ba)([rz])/;

println "m[0][0] " + m[0][0]
println "m[0][1] " + m[0][1]
println "m[0][2] " + m[0][2]
println "m[1][0] " + m[1][0]
println "m[1][1] " + m[1][1]
println "m[1][2] " + m[1][2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you give an example on when there could be multiple match objects (m[1])?

Comment: So there's an implicit `/g` for multi-match? Huh

Answer (score 1):

This is my best understanding of how to do this using Groovy syntax (but see lfaraone's response too):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher

def txt = 'abc : groovy : def'
if (txt =~ ~/ : (.+?) : /) {
    def match = Matcher.lastMatcher[0][1]
    println "MATCH=$match"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think your code will fail with an IndexOutOfBoundsException if there is no match. I edited my post before I saw your reply - so you might want to revisit your post. Please see the stuff about the m[0][1] notation.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer. Also, a Matcher in Java can have multiple matches. (Think of the /g flag for Perl matches.) The first index allows you to specify the match you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you want to use the `group()` method to retrieve the group match, the match code needs to be put into a conditional.

Take this code:

```java
def subject = "CN=mycn,EMAIL=mycn@foo.com"
if (match1 = subject =~ /CN=(.*?),.*/) {
    println match1.group(1)
}

def match2 = subject =~ /CN=(.*?),.*/
println match2.group(1)
```

The output of running the above code (in Groovy 3.09, JVM 17.0.1) is:

```
mycn

Caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java_util_regex_MatchResult$group.call(Unknown Source)
    at jdoodle.run(jdoodle.groovy:7)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

So `match1.group(1)` succeeds and returns the correct match `mycn`.

`match2.group(2)` results in an `IllegalStateException`.

So the `match` instance is only fully evaluated inside the conditional.