# How do we fetch multiple occurrences of a regex in a single string in Groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a string that I need to fetch the ID field from -

```
{"jobs":[{"id":"6369c112a2ee5ca08adaa1d01b7e5c74","status":"RUNNING"},{"id":"bbfd87f15334c8e27b40bc46896e95c7","status":"RUNNING"},{"id":"90c5a32e8300da7d43ce351f7f72f0d2","status":"RUNNING"}]}
```

What I would need all the matched IDs stored in an array.

I tried with the following regex, but couldn't fetch the string -

```
/"id"\ *:\ *"(.*?)"/
/"id"\ *:\ *"(?<id>.*?)"/
```

I'm not sure if it matches and I'm not sure how to fetch the matched data.

Comment: It matches the id in the first capturing group. Perhaps this page can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764387/groovy-syntax-for-regular-expression-matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def str = '{"jobs":[{"id":"6369c112a2ee5ca08adaa1d01b7e5c74","status":"RUNNING"},{"id":"bbfd87f15334c8e27b40bc46896e95c7","status":"RUNNING"},{"id":"90c5a32e8300da7d43ce351f7f72f0d2","status":"RUNNING"}]}'
def pattern = /(?<="id":")\w+(?=")/
def matcher = str =~ /$pattern/
assert matcher.collect() == ["6369c112a2ee5ca08adaa1d01b7e5c74", "bbfd87f15334c8e27b40bc46896e95c7", "90c5a32e8300da7d43ce351f7f72f0d2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's surely more appropriate to process your input with a JSON parser. It is JSON:

```
def s = '''{"jobs":
                 [{"id":"6369c112a2ee5ca08adaa1d01b7e5c74","status":"RUNNING"},
                  {"id":"bbfd87f15334c8e27b40bc46896e95c7","status":"RUNNING"},
                  {"id":"90c5a32e8300da7d43ce351f7f72f0d2","status":"RUNNING"}]}'''

def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(s.bytes).jobs.collect{it.id}
```

And that sets `ids` to `[6369c112a2ee5ca08adaa1d01b7e5c74, bbfd87f15334c8e27b40bc46896e95c7, 90c5a32e8300da7d43ce351f7f72f0d2]`