# renameing .fromFilePairs with regex capture group in closure

Tags: java, regex, groovy, regex-group, nextflow

I'm new to nextflow/groovy/java and i'm running into some difficulty with a simple regular expression task.

I'm trying to alter the labels of some file pairs.
It is my understanding that `fromFilePairs` returns a data structure of the form:

```
[
    [common_prefix, [file1, file2]],
    [common_prefix, [file3, file4]]
]
```

I further thought that:

- The `.name` method when invoked on a item from this list will give the name, what I have labelled above as `common_prefix`
- The value returned by a closure used with `fromFilePairs` sets the names of the file pairs.
- The value of `it` in a closure used with `fromFilePairs` is a single item from the list of file pairs.

however, I have tried many variants on the following without success:

```
params.fastq = "$baseDir/data/fastqs/*_{1,2}_*.fq.gz"

Channel
    .fromFilePairs(params.fastq, checkIfExists:true) {
        file -> 
            // println file.name // returned the common file prefix as I expected
            mt = file.name =~ /(common)_(prefix)/
            // println mt 
            // # java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(common)_(prefix) region=0,47 lastmatch=]
            // match objects appear empty despite testing with regexs I know to work correctly including simple stuff like (.*) to rule out issues with my regex
            // println mt.group(0) // #No match found
            mt.group(0) // or a composition like mt.group(0) + "-" + mt.group(1)
    }
    .view()
```

I've also tried some variant on this using the `replaceAll` method.

I've consulted documentation for, nextflow, groovy and java and I still can't figure out what I'm missing. I expect it's some stupid syntactic thing or a misunderstanding of the data structure but I'm tired of banging my head against it when it's probably obvious to someone who knows the language better - I'd appreciate anyone who can enlighten me on how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure can be provided to the [fromfilepairs operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) to implement a custom file pair grouping strategy. It takes a file and should return the grouping key. The example in the docs just groups the files by their file extensions:

```
Channel
    .fromFilePairs('/some/data/*', size: -1) { file -> file.extension }
    .view { ext, files -> "Files with the extension $ext are $files" }
```

This isn't necessary if all you want to do is alter the labels of some file pairs. You can use the [map operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) for this. The fromFilePairs op emits tuples in which the first element is the 'grouping key' of the matching pair and the second element is the 'list of files' (sorted lexicographically):

```
Channel
    .fromFilePairs(params.fastq, checkIfExists:true) \
    .map { group_key, files ->

        tuple( group_key.replaceAll(/common_prefix/, ""), files )
    } \
    .view()
```

Comment: Ah, thanks I see that I can do it with map that makes sense. I'm still not sure I understand what the closure on fromFilePairs is doing though as I think what I did should have given it twice as many groups as there are file pairs going by you description of the data structure, which I would have expected to produce at error not fail silently. Also if I had given it the correct number or group names shouldn't it still have just recreated the same grouping with different names, even if redefining the grouping is unnecessary to just to achieve renaming?

Comment: The data structure is basically what you have described: the channel emits tuples with two elements: a group key and a list of files. I don't think the code you have is failing silently exactly. I think the problem is that you needed to specify `size: -1`  as an option for the fromFilePairs op (like in the example above). The 'size' defines the number of files each emitted item is expected to hold and the default size is 2. So if your return key matched anything other than two files, then the item would not be emiited by the operator.

Comment: The anwer to your last question is yes. So I suppose you can create the grouping yourself if you wish. Just make sure it always returns the expected number of elements and you should be fine... Also, instead of returning `mt.group(0)`, try for example: `mt[0][1]`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/764503/751863