# Accessing multiple matches in a multiline string in groovy (matcher groups)

Tags: groovy, matcher

In groovy I have this multi-line string where I am trying to use a *matcher* and a regex *pattern* to extract the numbers using the [x][y] notation:

```
String input = """\
2234 This is a sample text
1424 This second 2335 line
This id third 455 line
Welcome to Tutorialspoint
        """.stripIndent()

println ((input =~ "^([0-9]+).*")[0][1])
println ((input =~ "^([0-9]+).*")[1][1])
```

When I run the above I get:

```
2234

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index is out of range -1..0 (index = 1)
```

So the first number 2234 I can access with `[0][1]` but how do I access the next number?

And more generally how is multidimensional array access to the matcher working + documented?

I found:

https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html

and:

[Groovy syntax for regular expression matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764387/groovy-syntax-for-regular-expression-matching)

but that does not really explain who multiple groups are accessed and why its necessary to use multidimensional indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String input = """\
    2234 This is a sample text
    1424 This second 2335 line
    This id third 455 line
    Welcome to Tutorialspoint
    """.stripIndent()
    
input.findAll(/[0-9]+/)
```

if you want only number at the beginning of each line:

```
input.findAll(/(?m)^[0-9]+/)
```

in your case regular expression matches the whole string.

you can specify multiline flag `(?m)` to process input line-by-line

```
println ((input =~ "(?m)^([0-9]+).*")[0][1])
println ((input =~ /(?m)^([0-9]+).*/)[1][1])
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE

Comment: Ok my point was more to understand/how to use [x][y] notation.