# Regex matcher returns multiple values

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm extracting a substring from a filename with format `xxxxx_ID.extension`

Example of strings that match correctly:

```
aaaa_bbbb_ID1.txt
xxxxxx_yy_ID2.xml
xxxx_ID3.zzz
```

I need the ID part. I tried with

```
def fileMatch = ("aaaa_bbbb_ID1.txt" =~ /(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=\.\w+$)/);
assert fileMatch.size() > 0
println fileMatch[0]
```

Where:

- `(?<=_)` to match the last underscore
- `([^_]+)` matches the ID to be extracted (a string with no underscore inside)
- `(?=\.\w+$)` to match the
  extension

It returns `[ID1, ID1]`. Here I was expecting just one result, why does it match the ID twice?

I know I could extract the first match with `fileMatch[0][0]` but I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong.

I also tried `(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=\.[^.]+$)` with the same result.

Comment: This explains why [Groovy syntax for regular expression matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/764503/5424988)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find a regex match with `=~` operator in Groovy, you can either obtain a whole match using `fileMatch[0]` - if there are no capturing groups in the pattern, or a list with the whole match and "captured" substrings (if you specified capturing groups in the pattern).

If you remove the capturing group (i.e. if you remove the capturing parentheses, `([^_]+)` => `[^_]+`) use

```
/(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.\w+$)/
```

You can obtain the whole match text with `fileMatch[0]`.

With `fileMatch.size()`, you check if there are those "captured" substrings with explicit capturing groups in your pattern. So, if there are capturing groups, you will be able to access them via `fileMatch[0][0]`, `fileMatch[0][1]`, etc.

Note that the number of "groups" is the number of capturing groups in the pattern + 1 (a group for the entire match value).

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about the complexity, but `\(ID.*)(\..*)\` may do the job